# How to remove space in array values?

Tags: php

I'm iterating through an XML and get a specific node. This node will be saved into an array but there is a problem. The array values have a space like this:

```
array(4) { ["host"]=> string(55) " localhost " ["username"]=> string(50) " root " ["dbName"]=> string(56) " test " ["dbPass"]=> string(52) " 123456 " }
```

You can see each values have a space before and after the value. The final result that I want achieve is this:

```
array(4) { ["host"]=> string(55) "localhost" ["username"]=> string(50) "root" ["dbName"]=> string(56) "test" ["dbPass"]=> string(52) "123456" }
```

If I do `trim($array_node)` I get an empty array.

Comment: Provide your usage in the iteration.

Comment: Well I didn't look close enough.  In the question you stated _"The array index have a space"_ but the spaces are not in the indexes, but the values.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, yes.. sorry for bad explain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $array_node is the array itself, rather than one of the values within it, then that would explain why you are getting back an empty array.

A quick solution to apply the 'trim' function to all the values in the array would be the following:

```
$result_array = array_map('trim', $source_array);
```

Comment: Working fine, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to do this when building the array, but you don't show that code.  To do it after the fact, just trim:

```
$result = array_map('trim', $array);
```

You originally stated array **index** multiple times.  This would do it for the index:

```
$result = array_combine(array_map('trim', array_keys($array)), $array);
```